Calculus of residues; $\frac{f'}{f}$

Let $U \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be an open set, $z_0 \in U$ and $f: U-\{z_0\} \to \mathbb{C}^*$ an analytic function such that $\DeclareMathOperator{\ord}{ord} \ord(z_0,f) \in \mathbb{Z}^*$. Then $z_0$ is a simple pole of $\frac{f'}{f}$ and
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{\res}{res} 
\res \biggl(\!z_0, \frac{f'}{f} \biggr) = \ord(z_0,f), 
$$

As $\ord(z_0,f) \in \mathbb{Z^*}$,
$$
\ord\biggl(\!z_0, \frac{f'}{f}\biggr) 
= \ord(z_0, f') - \ord(z_0, f) 
= \ord(z_0, f) - 1 -\ord(z_0,f) = -1. 
$$
Let $0 \neq k = \ord(z_0, f)$. Then
$$
\res\biggl(\!z_0, \frac{f'}{f}\biggr) 
= \lim_{z \to z_0}(z - z_0) \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} 
= \lim_{z \to z_0}(z - z_0) \frac{ka_k(z-z_0)^{k-1} + \dots{}}{a_k(z-z_0)^k + \dots{}} 
= k\frac{a_k}{a_k} 
= k 
= \ord(z_0, f).
$$
Is this a correct approach? Is there a more general result for
$$
\res\biggl(\!z_0, \frac{f^{n}}{f}\biggr)
$$
and should we be careful with the order of the derivative as we could reach a point where the order of the pole $z_0$ is $0$?

You've essentially proven the Argument Principle. It also works if $f$ is meromorphic with a pole at $z_0$, in which case the residue is the negative of the order of the pole. It's also clear that the residue is $0$ if $f$ has neither a pole nor a zero at $z_0$, since then $f'/f$ is holomorphic at $z_0$.
